# Storing multiple passwords

Tags: python-3.x

I need to be able to store multiple usernames in a separate text file and access each username individually.

My code currently writes them all on the same line

This is what i have got

```
start=input("Please enter either Login or Signup.")

if start=="Signup":
    First_name=input("Please enter your first name")
    Last_name=input("Please enter your last name")
    age=input("Please enter your age")
    Usernames=open("Username_file","r")
    Username1=(Usernames.read())


    Username=(First_name[0:3])+age
    Usernames=open("Username_file","w")
    Usernames.write(Username1)
    Usernames.write(Username)
    Usernames.close()
    Usernames=open("Username_file","r")
    for line in Usernames: 
        print (line)
```

Comment: Write a `\n` between the names.

Comment: It is only the usernames. Do you know a solution

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to use "with open(yourfile) as f:"

Comment: @A.wilson what exactly are you trying to achieve, at the moment the question is unclear. Do you want to have a file for first names and a file for last names?...

Comment: Basically it creates a username with your name and age. I need this to be stored, however i need to be able to store more than one and access each seperatly

Comment: `write` will just append the string to the existing content as is, you might want to use `print`

Comment: @forumulator no it won't as in this case, he as opened the `file` in `write` mode which effectively blanks the file. So the call to `write` does not append to the file before it was opened, it just appends to a new empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You are going about it the wrong way:

If you just want to add their first and last names to the end of the file `'Username_file.txt'`, you are doing it too complicatedly. Currently, your reading in the entire file to a variable and then writing the contents of the file before (from that variable) and the inputted name back to the same file.

The docs state that `a` is an option for `open()` which allows you to `append` to the file. This means you can just write the new username on without having to open it twice writing the same thing.

To do this, your code could look something like:

```
start = input("Please enter either Login or Signup: ")

if start == "Signup":
    First_name = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    Last_name = input("Please enter your last name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")

    with open("Username_file.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(First_name[0:3]+age+"\n")

    with open("Username_file.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Comment: You need to add a `"\n"`(or some other delimiter) at the end of each new username that you append to the end of the file, or you'll never be able to distinguish between the usernames.

Comment: it says there is an invalid syntax yet doesn't highlight anything in red

Comment: @A.wilson what line? I just ran it on my machine and it ran fine as expected

Comment: i dont know nothing is highlighted

Comment: I think it is the first with statement

Comment: @A.wilson the `syntax` is definitely correct as it's running on my machine without error

Comment: i do not know either i will check over again

Comment: @A.wilson I think I know what it is, I corrected a typo in one of the brackets in that with statement, re-copy out the code into your editor and it should then work

Comment: I get what you are saying though so instead of using your code i will write my own. Thanks

Comment: I have but i cant change the public score